# ImageView is resizing when dragging outside the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android application that adds an image/clipart on the picture. Everytime I drag the imageview on the right and bottom side of the layout, it automatically resize the image.

This is the sample scenario:

When I drag the clipart outide (TOP and Left Side of the layout), it doesnt resize the image but it cut the image (ClipArt1), but everytime I drag the image on the right and bottom side of the layout, it automatically resize, it does not exceed on the layout.

```
+-----------------------------+
|     * ClipArt*              |
|     *    1   *              |
|     **********              |
|                             |
|            *********        |
|            *ClipArt*        |
|            *   2   *        |
|            ********* ****** |
|                      * CA3* |
|                      ****** |
+-----------------------------+
```

This is my XML layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.61"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgstage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="stage" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tap" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this your whole layout or there is something else?

Comment: There is something else, but for sure it doesnt effect the layout.

Comment: I think its hard to solve issue without whole layout.Can you paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is incorrect - I experienced this in the past. My solution was to switch the root element of my dynamic container to a fixed-size RelativeLayout... Does this work?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.61"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgstage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="stage" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/tap" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```